# Memory error python computing permutations of list

Tags: python, python-2.7, permutation, combinatorics

I want to compute all possible ways of constructing a binary list of length n with the following line

```
combinations = map(list, itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n))
```

This works fine with low n's but I want to compute this for big n's (i.e. values between 25-35). Is there a better and more efficient way of producing this list?

Comment: I need a list of lists and either way this doesnt work on my computer, MemoryError for large n.

Comment: What is the end goal? Unless you need all the values at once, why not just keep the iterator rather than `map` to lists?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Memory error? Please provide the error output

Comment: This problem is fundamentally exponential in time and space (if you want to actually hold all the lists in memory). Sorry, there isn't much you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the list "lazily", so as to not store the entire thing in memory at once:

```
n = some-largish-value

for i in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=n):
   result = do_something_with(list(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are trying to find all the combinations of 0 and 1 for n term. Total number of such combination will be `2**n`. For `n=30`, total such combinations are `1073741824`. Huge isn't?

In order to get rid of the memory error, you should be using [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)  which `yield` the combinations dynamically instead of storing these as list. Also, since it is the combination of just 0s and 1s. Why not print binary numbers from `0` to `'1'*n`?

Below is the iterator to achieve this as:

```
def binary_combinations(num):
    my_binary_string = '1'*num
    my_int_num = int(my_binary_string, 2)
    format_string = '{'+':0{}b'.format(num)+'}'
    for i in xrange(my_int_num):
        yield format_string.format(i)
    else:
        raise StopIteration('End of Memory Issue!')
```

In order to execute this, do:

```
>>> for i in binary_combinations(3):
...     print i
...
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
```

Here `n = 3`. Now you may use it with n = 30, 40, .. OR whatever you want ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, if you really want a list of lists then your code is almost as memory efficient as it could be. Your issue is the size of the list, not the way you are computing it.

Do you realize that for n=35 you will have 1,202,590,842,880 elements? Most (if not all) desktop computers can't hold so many python integers in memory.